# Building glibc doesn't produce 64 bit libc.so.6

Tags: make, glibc, configure

I'm trying to build glibc with a 64bit version of libc.so.6 since a library I'm trying to use wants glibc_2.14+ but it isn't provided because the system I'm running on I don't have root access and the admin won't update the packages in order to maintain compatibility with installed software.

I've configured glibc using the following

```
../configure --prefix=/home/myuser/tools --enable-shared --with-binutils=/tmp/binutils-2.25.1
```

But after `make && make install` only `/home/myuser/tools/lib` contains a `libc.so.6` when the library I use needs a 64 bit version from lib64. How do I configure it so that it builds this way?

Additional info:

- This is running on a supercomputer node running CentOS, `uname -a` gives:

  ```
  Linux cgrid2 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 22 22:00:00 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```

Comment: what makes you think that the libc.so.6 you built is 32-bit?  run `file -L /home/myuser/tools/lib/libc.so.6` to verify.

Comment: @cas it is 64 bit, but the library I'm using doesn't use it, even though the lib64 dir is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: you need to add your library path and your include path to the gcc command line while compiling - e.g. by adding them to the CFLAGS env var (hint: `man gcc`, search for `-L` and `-I` options)

Comment: Okay I'll try that and report back. Though this is a cmake project that I have to compile

Comment: If you want your code to use the new gcc, you'll have to add `-Wl,--dynamic-linker` and `-Wl,-rpath` (e.g. https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/extend/ENV/std.rb#L62) as the ldso will otherwise try to load from it's hardcoded interpreter which points to /lib64/libc.so

Comment: And see the discussion at https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2015-03/msg00018.html